# How can I apply for a US tourist visa in a country where I am not resident?

Tags: visas, usa, consulates

I need to speak at a conference in the US in June. I have completed my applications and paid the requisite visa fees.

Now, I discovered that all available interview dates in the country of my residence are not favourable to my plans as I will be in Belgium on those dates. I am a resident of Spain).

Can I book my interview at the US consulate in Brussels instead of Madrid?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re traveling to a different destination and haven’t scheduled an appointment or been requested to go to a certain location already you will can request through the embassy closes to you to complete the process.
But if you have a document or email stating you need to go to this embassy to complete a process you will have to contact that embassy and see if they can switch you to a different location or you will have to return to that embassy to finish the process or postpone and reschedule a new appointment at that embassy for when you return there.